# most efficient malloc implementation for many small allocations?

Tags: c++, c, malloc

in my application there are tons of small `malloc`/`free` events with a high infant mortality rate.  Normally I would write my own memory pool, but after seeing the performance of using `tcmalloc` I am tempted to use a replacement malloc.  Are there any implementations with similar performance to a raw memory pool implementation?

For C++, I have another application that does the C++ `new`/`delete` dance.  Assume the same high infant mortality rate.  Two part question:

1) How would I implement a memory pool that acts on the `new` and `delete` operations?

2) Is there a transparent way, akin to the glibc malloc dynamic library features, to replace the `new`/`delete` memory allocator for all classes?

Comment: I think a better question would be why you insist on making "tons of small malloc/free events with a high infant mortality rate". This almost certainly reflects a bad design. Note that there is no portable way to replace `malloc`, but you could use another allocator (e.g. memory pool) running alongside or on top of `malloc`.

Comment: As an example to clarify... if you're using `malloc(N)` where `N<64` or so as a method to pass a result back to the caller, you'd almost surely be better off just returning a struct by value or having the caller pass a pointer to the destination (actually both are equivalent in real-world implementations). The only time it makes sense to use `malloc` for such small objects is when it's essential that the object be stationary in memory, e.g. to act as part of a linked list, tree, etc...

Comment: @R. In my current life, I'm trying to build a discrete event simulator.  In a former life, I came across this problem when building an order book for equities markets.  There are many situations where lots of entities must be tracked and enter/exit the system at random intervals.

Comment: You mentioned tcmalloc. I don't understand why you are still looking. Did tcmalloc not do what you need? Does it not perform well enough?

Comment: @Zan Lynx tcmalloc is performing well, but before settling I want to find out more about other solutions (based on real-life experiences).

Comment: I take it you have given nedmalloc a spin?

Comment: @Necrolis I actually haven't tried it yet -- will do so today

Comment: Could you settle for either the C or the C++ tag? Especially since you mention `malloc` this looks very `C` to me and not so much `++`.

Comment: @pmr I am going to ask the same question for new/delete, and it seemed a waste to ask a new question entirely

Comment: This question is platform-dependent by its nature, so you might want to add a platform-specific tag (e.g. `linux`).  Assuming you are talking about Linux, `new`/`delete` just forward to `malloc`/`free`, so hooking the latter will also hook the former.  That said, @R is right that you might be better off using value classes instead of allocating and freeing tons of tiny objects on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using boost pools?  I use that for my base small object allocator and have no complaint.  It has both thread safe and non-safe versions as well for ease of use.  There are also a bunch of other specific small object allocators out and about you can consider as well.

Comment: `boost::pools` is definitely C++-specific.  How does it perform?  Have you tried doing timing tests (rdtsc or wall-based)?

Comment: Nothing that specific, but look at it.  It's bascially an array based stack of fixed size memory addresses.  Alloc is a pop (read the array, update the pointer loc, return) and free is a push.  Nothing saying you couldn't do that in C yourself by just looking at the source of it.  If you need thread safety, then there's that cost too, but the concept is the same.  That's where I was going with that.

Comment: boost is portable, but both GCC and MSVC come with pools as well if you don't want portability or another library.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/). Not sure how it compares to tcmalloc exactly, but it doesn't hold on to all allocations as tcmalloc does.

Comment: In my test jemalloc was even slower than ptmalloc2 from glibc on small allocations.

Answer (score 0):

As for "how to write an allocator", `§ 20.6.9 [default.allocator]` has this to say about `std::allocator`:

```
#include <new>

// specialize for void:
template <> class allocator<void> {
public:
typedef void* pointer;
typedef const void* const_pointer;
// reference-to-void members are impossible.
typedef void value_type;
template <class U> struct rebind { typedef allocator<U> other; };
};

template <class T> class allocator {
public:
typedef size_t size_type;
typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
typedef T* pointer;
typedef const T* const_pointer;
typedef T& reference;
typedef const T& const_reference;
typedef T value_type;
template <class U> struct rebind { typedef allocator<U> other; };
allocator() throw();
allocator(const allocator&)  throw();
template <class U> allocator(const allocator<U>&)  throw();
~allocator();
pointer address(reference x) const  throw();
const_pointer address(const_reference x) const  throw();
pointer allocate(size_type, allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0);
void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)  throw();
size_type max_size() const  throw();
template<class U, class... Args>
void construct(U* p, Args&&... args);
template <class U>
void destroy(U* p);
};
```

You'd probably want to add helper member functions that behave more like the `new` and `delete` we're used to.

```
template<class... Args>
pointer alloc_and_constr(size_type n, Args&&... args);
template <class U>
pointer destr_and_dealloc(U* p);
```

Comment: This isn't meant to be a full answer, but just helpful info on a sub-question he had that I doubt many would address.

Answer (score 0):

Alexei Alexandrescu Small Object allocator in `std::allocator` wrapping:
[CodeProject article link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement)